How to set request timeout for pyodata
I have a pyodata client and send some requests to this backend.
Apparently something has changed on the other end and now some requests timeout. How can I react/abort these OData requests? I searched the documentation, there is nothing on timeouts.
Or do I need to use another library for that?
My code:
odata_session = requests.Session()
odata_session.auth = (
    settings.connections.username,
    settings.connections.password.get_secret_value(),
)

client = pyodata.Client(service_url, odata_session)

result = client.get_calculation().execute()

My question is not solved by the suggested question because that is just about plain python functions. I am talking about the pyodata requests.

This question is similar to: Timeout on a function call. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
